# Adding an event to S Planner on Button Click

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have a problem - I am making an app, and I want to add a new event to User's Calendar (I have a S Planner so I'm testing on it) on button click. The problem is when it comes to date and time - it just doesn't change. Here's code:

```
bCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent calintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    calintent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventname);
    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, city + ", " + street);
    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, timestart);
    startActivity(calintent);
}
});
```

timestart is a string which was passed through the other activity, for example "15:00".

I want to insert data from my activity into Samsung's S Planner. I have no problem with inserting everything except for date and time. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdlQw.jpg) Nothing changes there. If you need any further details, please tell.

Comment: from doc: *Intent Extras key: The start time of an event or an instance of a recurring event. **(milliseconds since epoch)*** ... so why you are trying to put string there?

Comment: What data type should I use then?

Comment: long...........

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it successfuly by using SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it thanks to Selvin's pointing out my mistake.
Made a string containing date and time and converted it using SimpleDateFormat
to long.

```
bCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent calintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                String dateString = datestart+" "+timestart;
                SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                try{
                Date d = f.parse(dateString);
                    long millis = d.getTime();
                    calintent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventname);
                    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, city + ", " + street);
                    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
                    calintent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, millis);
                    startActivity(calintent);
                } catch(ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```